# What effect does updating an indexed column with it's current value?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with an indexed column, named `status` declared as an int. What kind or performance effects would the following queries have?

```
UPDATE my_table set status = "1" WHERE status = 1
UPDATE my_table set status = 1 where status = 1
```

The reason I ask, other than curiosity, is I have an ORM, which updates each row in the table when update is called. And I was wondering if there were any performance impacts. I figured the extraneous writes would slow down the query and maybe having to update an index, but I'm only guessing.

Comment: The data is to be implicitly casted to the target type before writing to the storage. And has nothing to do with indexes.

Comment: I guess there would be a minor (very very minor) impact that the first option would be slower because the db-engine has to translate "1" to an int. My second GUESS is that MySQL-engine wouldn't actually do an update (because there's no reason).

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL ignores such an update (but it's the only DBMS that I know that does this - all other *will* update the column and the index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both cases will affect nothing. MySQL will search matched rows by corresponding condition, but also will realize that nothing should be done. Typecasting is out of the issue because will be done *before* comparison. Thus, affected rows count would be 0. Your result is quite as expected (sample):

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

for both cases, and affected rows:

```
mysql> SELECT ROW_COUNT();
+-------------+
| ROW_COUNT() |
+-------------+
|           0 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

This means MySQL will do nothing neither with value nor with index.